# Error when attempting to assign CoreData property an NSOrderedSet

Tags: ios, debugging, core-data, compiler-errors

I am currently practicing with CoreData and working with a project I found on the web. I am getting the error on one project but not the other. However it is not clear to me what the issue could be.

> " Cannot assign value of type 'NSOrderedSet' to type 'Location?' "

```
func saveRun()
{
    let savedRun = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName( "Run", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!) as! Run
    savedRun.distance = distance
    savedRun.duration = seconds
    savedRun.timestamp = NSDate()

    var savedLocations = [Location]()
    for location in locations
    {
        let savedLocation = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName( "Location", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext! ) as! Location
        savedLocation.timestamp = location.timestamp
        savedLocation.latitude = location.coordinate.latitude
        savedLocation.longitude = location.coordinate.longitude

        savedLocations.append( savedLocation )
    }
    savedRun.locations = NSOrderedSet(array: savedLocations)
}
```

[image]

The question I have is simply why is it that I can not assign the property locations the value of the NSOrderedSet in one project and can in the other & how can I go about resolving this issue?

Comment: What are the 2 projects?mhow are they different? The data type is wrong, where is it defines, was the model inadvertently edited?

Comment: @op did you fixed that issue?

Comment: @lifewithelliott, issue is fixed?

Answer (score -2):

I'm quite sure that CoreData doesn't support NSOrderedSet at all. It may support NSSet for one-to-many relations. NSSorderedSet is an interesting class that lets you treat items as a set, while being able to index them at the same time, and it is rarely used.

Comment: This is not correct, a Core Data *ordered* to-many relationship is represented as `NSOrderedSet`.

Comment: Nowadays you can indeed order a relationship in Core Data - just check the "ordered" box.